# Autenticação Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

Fala galera, então, recentemente comecei a estudar Laravel através de alguns livros/video aulas, e estou encasquetando a cabeça com uma coisa referente a autenticação.

Quando realizo o comando `php artisan make:auth` O Laravel me retorna

As Rotas

```
Auth::routes();
```

Os Controladores

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E as Views

Até ai tudo bem, mas rodando o comando `php artisan route:list` ele indica por exemplo que a rota acessada para fazer o login esta localizada em `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login`,  mas como podem ver na próxima imagem não existe este método `login` nessa classe `LoginController`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém que manja do assunto pode me explicar como funciona a autenticação do Laravel?

PS: Não consegui colocar todas as imagens, coloquei as principais então.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, vamos lá... você vê que o PHP está usando uma trait AuthenticatesUsers, essa trait é a página que você está procurando onde tem o método login e tb o logout.

No LoginController, Veja essa linha:

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Que usa esse namespace(caminho):

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
```

Agora, vamos lá na pasta:     vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Viu? Os métodos estão todos lá, está na pasta vendor(onde tem o próprio framework do laravel com todas as suas classes. Na pasta Auth você pode ver todo o código e saber mais sobre o comportamento da classe de autenticação. Sugiro a você que leia um pouco da autenticação e assista alguns vídeos no laracasts.

Comment: Obrigado Ivo, agora deu para entender como funciona mais ou menos essa autenticação, para falar a verdade, eu não sabia muito bem o que era esse tal de Illuminate, mas agora já sei onde encontrar ele e ver o funcionamento.